# Create data frame from values in every two continuous rows from an existing data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data frame `z1`:

```
z1 <- data.frame(time=as.factor(rep(0.5:9.5,times=rep(c(9,10,8,11,12),2))),
            roi= rep(c(1:9,1:10,1:8,1:11,1:12),2), area=runif(100, 5.0, 7.5))
```

I want to create a new data frame `z2` has `10*nrow(z1)` rows with condition:
    at each `time` value, every second row `(z1$roi[i:i+1] and z1$area[i:i+1])` for `i in 1: c(nrow(z1) -1)` are used to make column `roi` and `area` in `z2`, like

```
z2$roi <- seq(z1$roi[i],z1$roi[i+1], length.out = 10)
z2$area <- seq(z1$area[i],z1$area[i+1], length.out = 10)
```

If the data frame `z1` looks like:

```
    time roi     area
1    0.5   1 6.181150    #=z1$roi[1]
2    0.5   2 5.469366    #=z1$roi[2]
3    0.5   3 6.742525
.
.
.
98   9.5  10 6.063234
99   9.5  11 6.824393    #=z1$roi[99]
100  9.5  12 7.346298    #=z1$roi[100]
```

the data frame `z2` would be:

```
     time  roi      area
1     0.5 1.000000 6.181150     #=z1$roi[1]
2     0.5 1.111111 6.102063
.
.
.
9     0.5 1.888889 5.548453
10    0.5 2.000000 5.469366     #=z1$roi[2]
.
.
.
991   9.5 11.00000 6.824393     #=z1$roi[99]
992   9.5 11.11111 6.882383
.
.
.
999   9.5 11.88889 7.288309
1000  9.5 12.00000 7.346298     #=z1$roi[100]
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: your row numbers are wrong in expected output

Comment: Sounds like a linear interpolation problem. E.g. - see `?approx` - you could specify the sequence values between each row as the `xout=` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `tidyverse`, changing a bit your values to appreciate the output (replace `5` by `10`):

```
z1 <- head(z1,3)

library(tidyverse)

z1 %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(roi,area),~map2(.,c(.[-1],last(.)),~seq(.x,.y,length.out=5))) %>%
  unnest %>%
  head(-5)

#    time  roi     area
# 1   0.5 1.00 6.302351
# 2   0.5 1.25 6.151644
# 3   0.5 1.50 6.000938
# 4   0.5 1.75 5.850231
# 5   0.5 2.00 5.699525
# 6   0.5 2.00 5.699525
# 7   0.5 2.25 5.687045
# 8   0.5 2.50 5.674566
# 9   0.5 2.75 5.662087
# 10  0.5 3.00 5.649608
```

- We will apply the same transformations to cols `time` and `area`, so we use `mutate_at` on those.
- We want to transform them into list columns containing vectors, so we can `unnest` afterwards and get a long `data.frame`(you may need to get acquainted with `tidyr::unnest` to understand this step, basically it makes a 'regular' `data.frame` out of a `data.frame` that would have `vectors`, `lists`, or nested `data.frames` as elements).
- The map family will return such a list output, but each value depends on current AND next value, so we use `purrr::map2` to get both input.
- `.` is current value, `c(.[-1],last(.))` is the next value (for last element there is no next value, so we keep the last value).
- We unnest to create a long `data.frames`.
- The repeated last value created duplicated rows, so we remove them with `head(-n)`

Comment: @ Moody, thousand thanks. That what I expected. But I would like to understand the syntax, it would be great if you spend some time to explain briefly :) :)

Comment: @ Moody, that makes sense to me :). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You could do this as a linear interpolation problem using `approx()`:

```
s1 <- seq_len(nrow(z1)-1)
s2 <- rep(s1,each=9)

out <- approx(
  x    = seq_along(z1$area),
  y    = z1$area,
  xout = c(s2 + head(seq(0,1,length.out=10),-1), nrow(z1))
)$y

z1

#  time roi     area
#1  0.5   1 6.413124
#2  0.5   2 6.837422
#3  0.5   3 6.656612
```

And then just join the results back together using row indexing:

```
cbind(z1[c(s2,nrow(z1)),], out)

#    time roi     area      out
#1    0.5   1 6.413124 6.413124
#1.1  0.5   1 6.413124 6.460268
#1.2  0.5   1 6.413124 6.507413
#1.3  0.5   1 6.413124 6.554557
#1.4  0.5   1 6.413124 6.601701
#1.5  0.5   1 6.413124 6.648845
#1.6  0.5   1 6.413124 6.695989
#1.7  0.5   1 6.413124 6.743134
#1.8  0.5   1 6.413124 6.790278
#2    0.5   2 6.837422 6.837422
#2.1  0.5   2 6.837422 6.817332
#2.2  0.5   2 6.837422 6.797242
#2.3  0.5   2 6.837422 6.777152
#2.4  0.5   2 6.837422 6.757062
#2.5  0.5   2 6.837422 6.736972
#2.6  0.5   2 6.837422 6.716882
#2.7  0.5   2 6.837422 6.696792
#2.8  0.5   2 6.837422 6.676702
#3    0.5   3 6.656612 6.656612
```

This sort of logic should scale *much* better than having to calculate a sequence for each row. Something of the order of 10 secs vs 1 minute for 1 million rows from a quick and dirty test.

Comment: Thank for your answer. If I want to sequence "roi" column, I will do the same to what you did with "area"?

Comment: @HoangLe - approx returns an "x" value as well as the "y" - which should be the partial "roi" values (in this case equal to the specified xout= argument)